# How to identify which button is clicked in dynamically allocated buttons in Window Store App

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8

I am developing Windows 8 App. Buttons are dynamically populated in ListView. I've created a click event, but how do I identify that which button is selected? The code I wrote is also not working, here it is

```
TextBlock lblUserName = new TextBlock();
lblUserName = (TextBlock)lstPeoples.FindName("lblUserName");
pageTitle.Text = lblUserName.Text;
```

The XAML Code for the list view is as follows

```
<ListView x:Name="lstPeoples" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="571" Margin="34,47,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="455" SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderBrush="White">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="80">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image x:Name="imgUser" Height="150" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblUserName" Text="{Binding UName}" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"  Width="400"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Add Friend" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Seeking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In button click event handler, use the sender object parameter to locate the Button control and work your way through the visual items to find the TextBlock.

For example,

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var grid = (Grid)button.Parent;
    var lblUserName = (TextBlock)grid.FindName("lblUserName");
    pageTitle.Text = lblUserName.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var button = (Button)sender;
dynamic viewModel = button.DataContext;
pageTitle.Text = viewModel.UName;
```

Comment: I was thinking of binding the name to a lookup property on the viewmodel, but this is even better!

Comment: Well, I would actually cast it to the view model type instead of using dynamics or better yet - use a command on the view model. The bigger problem is the design - having a separate button on each item in the `ListView`. I wouldn't do that - it's a waste of space.

Comment: It really depends on what each item represents.  I'm currently working on an app where each listview item can have 500+ buttons on it, but I certainly agree about using commands vs casting the sender.

Comment: What if I want to populate button as per my need?

Comment: I want to add buttons in list view as per my need, how can I achieve that?

Comment: In each item? Well there are a few ways to do it, but I don't want to encourage it. The standard UX is you select an item or items and the app bar has the buttons to operate on selected items. You can show the app bar automatically when an item gets selected. If you need something special happen in a list item you can put the `ItemTemplate` contents in a `UserControl` and then the `UserControl` can encapsulate more logic than would be sensible straight in a `DataTemplate`.